# htaccess allow .txt files

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

In a web folder, I currently cannot access `.txt` files via URL in browser. How can I modify my `htaccess` file, so that files with type `.txt` can be accessed via URL in browser?

Comment: What does your logs say when you try to access a .txt file? What does it say in your access and error logs?

Comment: Depends on your setup, your OS, etc, try google.

Comment: I have a Rails project, and in the log folder there are development.log, dispatcher.log, production.log, server.log, and test.log. Any one of them might be useful?

Comment: Your webserver logs, not your app logs

Comment: @John Why don't you show us your .htaccess file ?

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos It's currently empty.

Comment: @John Your comment said this is for a RAILS application. Is it safe to assume you're using Passenger in combination with Apache? If so, can you post your `<VirtualHost>` for the RAILS app? Either way, we need more information. What does the apache error/access log say?

Comment: @John Can you paste your .htaccess file here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If adding the settings into your .htaccess file that Sergio mentioned isn't working, you may have to go straight to your VirtualHost entry. and add the rules. I'll let the more experienced apache folks here chime in, but that's where I would go.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the code below in htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt)$">
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This will permit access to all txt files. If you wish to deny all except one specific file:

```
 Order Deny,Allow 
 Deny from All 
<Files "view_only_this_file.txt"> 
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Allow from All 
</Files>
```

Comment: I added your code to the end of my `.htaccess` in the `public` folder of my Rails project (which is the folder used to store public files.) However, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: this solution helped me to verify SSL authentication text  file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Sergio! I have changed your code to allow a specific txt-file:

```
<Files "unternehmenscocktail.txt"> 
  Order Deny,Allow 
  Allow from all
</Files>
```